# dict comprehension with condition and keyword check

Tags: python, dictionary, list-comprehension

I am trying to accomplish something like this:

```
models = {k1: v, k2:v}
grid = {k1: w, k2:w, k3:w}

grid_of_params = {grid.items() if grid.keys() in models for k,v in grid.items()}

print(grid_of_params)
Output: {k1: w, k2:w}
```

In other words, a dict comprehension which returns items of a dict `grid` if their keys are present in the dict `models`.

How to correct this syntax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, `{k:v for k, v in grid.items() if k in models}` should do the trick.